# Creating Android Shape with rounded corners and shadow and custom image

Tags: android, xml, drawable, shapes

I'm trying to create a `shape` for `ImageView` that would have round corners, the actual `image` and a shadow. When I created a `shape` and set the following variables then I got myself a rounded image with some shadow:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#42000000" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Now when I tried to add my custom image (like many people suggested I used `Layer-list` I got the image but the rounded corners and shadow was gone :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#42000000" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/no_cover_art" />
</layer-list>
```

Also I will be changing``Images` programatically so maybe that is also something that needs to be mentioned.

What am I doing wrong and how do I get the rounded corners with shadows and custom image?

**EDIT**
I have tried using only the shape as a drawable, but I get a result where it applies the corners to something behind it and does not change the `ImageView` itself.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/song_album_cover"
android:layout_width="64dp"
android:layout_height="68dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
android:elevation="18dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_cover_art"
android:background="@drawable/artist_cover_image"/>
```

On the left side is a picture of what `Android Studio` shows me and on the right side is the image from when I actually run the app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the drawable as the background for the image view and then set the src to whatever image you want.

Comment: When using the `shape` as drawable and image with `app:srcCompat="`, it seems like it overrides it and does not take the shape

Answer (score -1):

/*use need to use this below thing in the imageview and put your code in the drawable file and then add in the below way*/
android:background="@drawable/nameofdrawablefile"